# Git hook post-merge

Tags: git, hook

I have a post-receive hook that create a file after a push on master branch

```
branch_name=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
if [ "master" == "$branch_name" ]; then
    touch OK_push.txt
fi
```

Is it possible to do the same thing after a merge (or pull) between one branch on master branch?

Answer (score 1):

If you read through [the list of available hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks), you see that there is a `post-merge` hook...

...but it's not clear from your question that this will do what you want.  A `post-receive` hook runs *on a remote git repository* after receiving updates from a client, while a `post-merge` hooks runs *in your local repository* after a merge operation (including `git pull`, unless you've set git to rebase rather than merge).